# How Do I Efficiently Set Values From Sting and Array Resources?

Tags: android, arrays, string, resources, key-value

I'm a noob to android development and I want to know if there is an efficient method of setting values from string and array resources.  I have very large amount of string and arrya resources that must be accessed when a user selects a value from a  very long listview. For example, if the listview contained Acne, Bruise,etc would it be possible to set values as such:

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.ailmentslistview:

        String value = ((TextView) arg1).getText();

        remedyDescription.setText(R.string.value_description);
        remedyCause.setText(R.string.value_cause);
        remedyHerbs.setText(R.string.value_herbs);
        remedyFoods.setText(R.string.value_foods);
        remedyListSupplements = res.getStringArray(R.array.value_supplements);
        remedyListDosage = res.getStringArray(R.array.value_dosage);
        remedyListComments = res.getStringArray(R.array.value_comment);

        break
        }
     }
```

Instead of:

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.ailmentslistview:

            if(String value = ((TextView) arg1).getText()==Acne){

        remedyDescription.setText(R.string.acne_description);
        remedyCause.setText(R.string.acne_cause);
        remedyHerbs.setText(R.string.acne_herbs);
        remedyFoods.setText(R.string.acne_foods);
        remedyListDosage = res.getStringArray(R.array.acne_dosage);
        remedyListComments = res.getStringArray(R.array.acne_comment);

            }else if(String value = ((TextView) arg1).getText()==Bruise) {

        remedyDescription.setText(R.string.bruise_description);
        remedyCause.setText(R.string.bruise_cause);
        remedyHerbs.setText(R.string.bruise_herbs);
        remedyFoods.setText(R.string.bruise_foods);
        remedyListDosage = res.getStringArray(R.array.bruise_dosage);
        remedyListComments = res.getStringArray(R.array.bruise_comment);

            }


                break;
            }
  }
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray. for string. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray. for string array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)**
 for dynamic resource loading.

context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", context.getApplicationInfo().packageName);

In your case, you can create the string name by,

String value = ((TextView) arg1).getText();

name = value.toLowerCase() + "_description";

and so..

Comment: Thanks.  You just saved me so much unnecessary typing.

Answer (score 1):

```
String myString    = getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.myString);
String []  myArray = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
```

[For more info.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I understand how to get and set from resource.  I want to know if it is possible to use a dynamic value to access particular resources.

Comment: can you explain it a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

String myString    = getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.myString);
String []  myArray = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);